# Vicidial Agent API

Tags: php, html, asterisk, voip, vici

I'm trying to implement an avatar like system in vicidial. here's what I came up after searching so far. I created a web form then when a call comes to an agent screen they will just click on the webform and they will see buttons as to which pre-recorded file will play. Based on my research this can be implemented using the vicidial agent API, my problem is I don't know how to use the API, I've tried to integrate it into a button but I can't hear the recording play.

```
<button >
  Monday
  <a href="http://serverip/agc/api.php?source=test&user=testuser&pass=testuserpass&agent_user=testuser&function=audio_playback&value=monday.wav&stage=PLAY">play</a>

</button>
```

here's the output after pressing the button

> SUCCESS: audio_playback function sent - mondaywav|PLAY|testuser

But recording is not playing. Please help.

UPDATE:

I check asterisk logs and i got this warning

[Sep 23 14:58:41] WARNING[11014][C-00001147]: channel.c:6009 ast_request: No channel type registered for ''
[Sep 23 14:58:41] WARNING[11014][C-00001147]: app_dial.c:2455 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type '' (cause 66 - Channel not implemented)

Comment: ) For avatar like system you need know ALOT of asterisk. Check first audiohooks, asterisk dialout,profiling and writing c/c++ app for asterisk.

Answer (score 3):

Agent Audio soundboards is now a part of the VICIdial open source codebase. Just upgrade your system, enabled the feature in System Settings, and you are all set.